# Triggering jquery with a change in an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thanks for helping

I have a input that users put links or urls. What I do is when someone enters a url into the input jquery script connects to php script which gives some information about the url. Just like facebook share.

I use this code

```
$('.input-class').keyup(function(event){

  $('.message').html('thanks for the url');
});
```

the problem with using keyup it work when you type something with the keyboard. Usually users copy and paste the url into the input. so, if they copy and past this is not working.

then I tried .change()

```
$('.input-class').change(function(event){

  $('.message').html('thanks for the url');
});
```

but there is a problem with this as well. it works when the input loses the focus.

I need something should work what ever user type or paste into the input jquery should be triggered.

What should I do? Can I use change and keyup together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`change` event is completely different, it gets triggered when the value changes which is evaluated when the element under question is out of focus.

Use `input` event as well which will get triggered when the text content of an element is changed through the user interface.

```
$('.input-class').on('keyup input', function(event){
   $('.message').html('thanks for the url');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try on change Event, Make sure this will work in higher version of jQuery

```
jQuery('.input-class').on('change', function(e){
   jQuery('.message').html('thanks for the url');
});
```

For Lower version of jQuery Use

```
jQuery('.input-class').live('change', function(e){
   jQuery('.message').html('thanks for the url');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Trigger an `input` event:

```
$('.input-class').on('input', function(event){
```